# Formula for consecutive heads or tails in x coin flips.

Tags: probability

If I flip a coin 3 times it is simple to show that

- At least 1 is head or tail  = 1.0 # obvious
- At least 2 consecutive are head or tail = 0.75

$6 / 8 = 0.75$

[image: Blue satisfies the conditions red doesn't.]

- At least 3 consecutive are head or tail = 0.25

$2 / 8 = 0.25$

[image: Blue satisfies the conditions red doesn't.]

Calculating when at least x consecutive are head or tail is not so easy when you start flipping a lot of coins as the number of posibilities is $2^n$ where n is the number of coin flips.

I thougth the problem was interesting enough to deserve writing a programme for it.

Still after looking to the outputs of the programme I can not find a formula / procedure that will give me the answer without needing to enumerate all the possibilities.

Can you please give me a motivated formula (I mean a formula and an intuitive explanation of it) that having as the input:

- $a$ = number of coin flips
- $b$ = so many consecutive heads or tails

will tell me the probability of how many times that happens?
(Ex. $f(3,2)$ => 0.75 )

Comment: "when you start flipping a lot of coins"? Did you mean "when you start flipping the coin a lot of times"?

Comment: @barakmanos Yes I mean that.

Comment: @user3105485 Have you found a solution? Are you still interested in an answer?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I am still surely interested in the solution, but this problem feels above my current level of Math skill so I have not really made progress on it

Comment: My 7th grade teacher posed the question as at least 4 Heads in a row out of 20 flips, and asked students to guess the answer (it's just a bit below 50%). I was able to brute force compute the answer with a simple node.js program, but quickly realized that trying to calculate this for anything like 100 flips would take ages for my laptop to compute. I'd like a formula!